# Problem updating variable in main function after calculations in another function

Tags: python

Basically, I have a list of numbers as a variable in my main function. I call another function to temporarily combine that list with another list into a dictionary to perform calculations. Then, I split the dictionary back into lists and return the variables. For some reason, the variable y didn't update in the main function

```
def main():
    
    x = 'ABC'
    y = [1,1,1]
    
    while True:
        print(y)
        reply = input()

        a_function(x, y)
    
        if reply == '':
            break

def a_function(x, y):
    
    dictionary = dict(zip(x, y))
    
    dictionary['A'] += 1
    
    y = dictionary.values()
    
    return y

main()
```

Current Output: `y = [1,1,1]`, `y = [1,1,1]`....

Expected Output: `y = [2,1,1]`, `y = [3,1,1]`, `y = [4,1,1]`

Comment: You aren't setting the return value from `a_function` to anything in `main` so the values in `main` stay the same. You need `y = a_function(x,y)` for the value of `y` in `main` to update.

Comment: @cookesd Can you comment that again as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting the return value from `a_function` to anything in main so the values in `main` stay the same. In main you need to change your call to `a_function` to:

`y = a_function(x,y)`

for the value of `y` in main to update.